# Qubit Resource Estimates for 2D Ising Model

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, circuit-construction, error-correction, noise

I recently came across [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.07112.pdf) where the 1d Transverse Field Ising Model (TFIM) with $n$ spins was simulated on a quantum computer. The estimated resources were $n^2$ for the number of gates and the circuit depth was $n \log(n).$ Since the 1d TFIM is equivalent to the 2d Classical Ising Model (CIM) using transfer matrix methods ([see here](https://phas.ubc.ca/%7Eberciu/TEACHING/PHYS503/PROJECTS/05_mandy.pdf) or [here](http://web.mit.edu/8.334/www/grades/projects/projects12/TimHsieh.pdf)), I was wondering

> Would the estimated resources for the 2D CIM be the same as the TFIM?

My intuition says we would need more gates since we have a 2D square lattice of size $n^2$ rather than $n$ spins in the TFIM chain. I'm not certain about the circuit depth however. I would really appreciate anyone's thought process here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to QCSE. I recommend you edit your posting to restrict out to only one question. This website works best for single-question postings. You can always submit additional continuing questions later!

Comment: @MarkS Sure, thanks for the suggestion!